# Sideskirt repair

Tags: repair, plastic

During the winter period, a driver on the other side of the road crashed into his predecessor. A bumper was launched from that point and smacked right into the lower left side of my car, resulting in a hardly noticeable dent (which is not worth repairing) and a crack in the sideskirt.

As this sideskirt is composed of ABS plastic, what would be the easiest way to repair this cracked skirt? Simply replacing it by another skirt is not an option as this one is hard to get your hands on. The sideskirt has a diagonal crack of about 7cm (2.8inches) and is not completely broken.. yet

Thanks!

**EDIT:** As requested by Paulster, I have added some pictures of the crack. The car is a 2001 Toyota Celica (not really relevant).

[image: Crack from the front]

[image: At an angle]

As you can see on the first picture, the crack ends about 1cm from the top.
On the bottom side (not in the picture) the crack ends about 10 cm from the edge. At this point the skirt is not completely broken, though the cracked part is a gap.

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to go on here. Can you give us a picture of what you want to repair as well as the vehicle information so we know we are all on the same sheet of music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use acetone to *melt and weld* ABS plastic. Simply apply acetone to the broken edges and hold them together firmly. You could then reinforce it from behind the skirt by using epoxy ([loctite?](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/epxy_plstc_s/overview/Loctite-Epoxy-Plastic-Bonder.htm)) to glue improvised braces.
Alternatively, you could use scrap ABS as braces and stick them using acetone as well.
I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YIV0XVkkPE) among many other instructional videos showing exactly that.